# Compile multiple autoit scripts using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, compiler-construction, compilation, autoit

I have this autoit script:

```
Aut2exe.exe /in %cd%\n1.au3 /out %cd%\n1.exe /icon %cd%\icon.ico /x86 /comp 4
```

I need it to compile all scripts in the dir not just the file specified. I have tried this:

```
Aut2exe.exe /in %cd%\* /out %cd%\* /icon %cd%\icon.ico /x86 /comp 4
```

But it gives a error does any one know what I could do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion 

    for %%a in ("%cd%\*.au3") do (
        Aut2exe.exe /in "%%~fa" /out "%%~dpna.exe" /icon "%%~dpa\icon.ico" /x86 /comp 4
    )

    endlocal
```